# Voted and applied relay flags

Tags: flags

I've set up a exit, according to consensus-health.torproject.org it got voted Fast and Exit (I guess Flags shown as RED means that they were voted?).

I was monitoring the relay with arm and realized that my Connections tab was only showing Inbound/Outbound connections and no Exit. So, I checked consensus-health again and the flags were not applied yet (voted 24hrs ago).

Is it normal that it takes that long for flags to be applied? I've read 'lifecycle of a new relay' and according to it, it's also normal that your relay gets roughly no use in the first 3 days. I was concerned at first because my Advertised Bandwidth was only around 140kb/s -- but I've set no limits and according to the ISP it's 100mbit/s unmetered. I dont think they are throttling, but I will keep an eye on that after the 0-3 day timeframe anyways.